# Add fee based on specific cart total in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add fee based on specific amount in art total. I want to show if the cart total is equal to or greater than total "$$$" amount add the fee, otherwise don't add.

I know this works adding it to total, but I don't think it's checking to see if it is below dollar amount.

```
function woo_add_custom_fees(){

    $cart_total = 0;

    // Set here your percentage
    $percentage = 0.15;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){ 
        $cart_total += $item["line_total"];
    }
    $fee = $cart_total * $percentage;

    if (  WC()->cart->total >= 25 ) { 

     WC()->cart->add_fee( "Gratuity", $fee, false, '' );

    }

    else {

        return WC()->cart->total;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'woo_add_custom_fees' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'woo_add_custom_fees' );
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: the `else` part is the "below"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`** action hook, `WC()->cart->total` always return **`0`**, as this hook is fired before the cart total calculations…

> You should better use **`WC()->cart->cart_contents_total`** instead.

Also the cart object is already included in this hook, so you can add it as an argument in your hooked function. 
 Also you dont need to use this hook **`woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update`**.

Here is your revisited code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function custom_fee_based_on_cart_total( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // The percentage
    $percent = 15; // 15%
    // The cart total
    $cart_total = $cart->cart_contents_total; 

    // The conditional Calculation
    $fee = $cart_total >= 25 ? $cart_total * $percent / 100 : 0;

    if ( $fee != 0 ) 
        $cart->add_fee( __( "Gratuity", "woocommerce" ), $fee, false );
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helps

Comment: how to add select form to this code to choose required value? :)
Thank you!

Comment: @AlexLee See [those related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees+%28jquery%5D) for that