# How to adjust my WooCommerce Cart Fee to only apply under certain amounts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a fee of 105 excluding VAT to all orders under 2000 excluding VAT. But my code always adds the fee, even if over 2000.

```html
/**
 * Add custom fee to checkout section
 */
function woo_add_cart_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->total <= 2000 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __( 'Administrative Fee' ), 105 , true, 'standard'); //Add tax on 105
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

Comment: In `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` action hook, `WC()->cart->total` always return 0, as this hook is fired before the cart total calculation. You should better use `WC()->cart->cart_contents_total` instead. If you search for [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082596/add-fee-based-on-specific-cart-total-in-woocommerce/)/related questions, you will also find this answer. (so feel free to delete your question, as it has already been asked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` action hook you will get the `$cart` object as a paramater so based on that you can check cart total and also usgin that `$cart` object you can use the `add_fee()` function.

```
/**
 * Add custom fee to the checkout section
 */
function woo_add_cart_fee( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    if ( $cart->cart_contents_total <= 2000 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( __( 'Delivery Fee' ), 105, true, 'standard' ); //Add tax on 105
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]